# count occurrence of date (e.g 14th) between two dates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, php-carbon

How can I count occurrences of 14th of a month between two dates
For example between 07.05.2018 and 04.07.2018
I have 2 occurrences of the 14th

Comment: does `php-carbon` mean you use the [Carbon package](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)?

Comment: Yes, but 1.25 without CarbonPeriod

Comment: Ah okay, lemme see if I can write something up in plain php then.

Comment: @phper please have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Note that I've changed your date format, but you can just do a `createFromFormat` if you're really keen on your own format.

```
$startDate = new DateTime('2018-05-07');
$endDate = new DateTime('2018-07-04');

$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$datePeriod = new DatePeriod($startDate, $dateInterval, $endDate);

$fourteenths = [];

foreach ($datePeriod as $dt) {
    if ($dt->format('d') == '14') { // Note this is loosely checked!
        $fourteenths[] = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}

echo count($fourteenths) . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($fourteenths);
```

See it in action here: https://3v4l.org/vPZZ0

---

**EDIT**

This is probably not an optimal solution as you loop through every day in the date period and check whether it's the fourteenth. Probably easier is to modify the start date up to the next 14th and then check with an interval of `P1M`.

Comment: No problem! Note that if you end date is a 14th, it will not be taken into account btw.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop at all.
Here's a solution that does not loop at all and uses the less memory and performance hungry date opposed to DateTime.

```
$start = "2018-05-07";
$end = "2018-07-04";

$times = 0;

// Check if first and last month in the range has a 14th.
if(date("d", strtotime($start)) <= 14) $times++;
if(date("d", strtotime($end)) >= 14) $times++;

// Create an array with the months between start and end
$months = range(strtotime($start . "+1 month"), strtotime($end . "-1 month"), 86400*30);

// Add the count of the months
$times += count($months);

echo $times; // 2
```

https://3v4l.org/RevLg

Comment: Nice! I like datetimes for readability but this should work much much faster over larger periods of time.

Comment: @Loek wait! I have found a bug. It's not working correctly if going past new year.

Comment: @Loek now it works, but it's even harder to read now. But as you say DateTime is developer friendly, date and strtotime is more user-friendly being faster loading.

Comment: Haha yeah, this should really sport a good function name. That said, I'm suprised at how fast checking days in my solution is: https://3v4l.org/vPZZ0/perf#output

Comment: The times 3v4l outputs on the performance tab is not correct. But you can use microtime to get the times the functions uses. https://3v4l.org/NdA2Y

Comment: Holy crap that is a lot faster, props!

Comment: It depends on the version of PHP. Which to me is quite odd. Sure some versions may have a better version of DateTime or date, but the way it varies is odd in my opinion. I think we should not see it as the truth, but more as a guideline.  But yes. It is a lot faster. But keep in mind this is 14 months times 100 (1400 months) if it scales linear. I added `*100` on the times to remove the scientific output